# does reverse indexing result in contiguous memory?

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing, fortran

say I have a matrix declared as

```
double precision, dimension(100,50) :: a
```

is the section

```
a(:,50:48:-1)
```

contiguous in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the subaray `a(:,50:48:-1)` is not contiguous, although it occupies contiguous storage. Many situations will require a temporary array to be created.

```
 real, dimension(100,50) :: a

 call sub(a(:,50:48:-1))

contains
  subroutine sub(b)
    real :: b(:,:)
    print *, is_contiguous(b)
  end subroutine
end
```

and

```
> ifort contig.f90
> ./a.out
 F
```

Comment: Because the elements are not in the right order in memory. The elements of the subarray (or array `b`) are not in the simple column-major order.